# Pfsense web gui unacessible

Tags: networking, pfsense

I'm trying to set up my virtual lab and I'm running pfsense on a virtual machine. I have 2 network cards. One is bridged and the other one is on the custom network.
Im trying to log into web gui but the site is not accessible.
[image: freeBSD control panel]
[image]

Comment: It is probably an issue with your virtual network settings. Can you edit your question with a screenshot of the adapter settings?

Comment: Can you please check now?

Answer (score 0):

By design GUI is not reachable from the WAN direction.
You should do some configuration to achieve that.

Please check the following official pfsense article about the steps:
https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/recipes/remote-firewall-administration.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1141786)

Comment: Thank you @Toto . I do not change the answer this time but next time I follow your piece of advice.

Comment: Please do change the answer. This page is designed to have all the necessary information to fix a problem, and the reviews we write are meant to guide new users like you to integrate into the community. In order to become a helping part of it, you need reputation which you will only get if you write good answers. See the [help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)